# Is there a macOS App or Extension to increase line spacing and letter kerning for Safari Reader View?

Tags: macos, safari, applications, accessibility, safari-extensions

I love Reader View in conjunction with the "Speak Selection" Accessibility tool; I find that I retain the information more when I hear and read along with the text. However, the line spacing and letter kerning are too dense for me. Does anyone know of an App or Extension that can help with this?
AudioEye and other providers offer a great web solution, but it needs to be implemented at the source code by the website's developers.

Comment: Cmd/+ (plus) will increase overall font/appearance in Reader the same as regular view, though will preserve the relative leading/kerning aspect. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it doesn't; I'm looking for a way to augment the leading and kerning in addition to the line spacing.

Comment: OK, you maybe need some CSS solution, which I'm afraid is above my pay-grade. Wish you luck :)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Safari allows you to upload a custom CSS Style Sheet so I was thinking about toying around with that. I"m sure some JavaScript would also help, but I haven't ventured down that path yet (keyword- yet).